# How to programmatically fail Page validation in button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my button click, I would like to cause the page validation to fail if it meets a certain criteria. The problem is that that Page.IsValid is read-only.

This is what I am trying in my button click:

```
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls(container);

        MyBtn += MyBtn_Click;
        MyBtn += MyBtn_Click2; // Cannot move this
    }

    protected void MyBtn_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        CaptchaControl.Validate();
        if (!CaptchaControl.IsValid)
        {
            Page.IsValid = false; // Error because read-only
            // Stop before running MyBtn_Click2!
        }
    }
```

If my captcha fails validation, I want to return to the page immediately, before it starts running the 2nd click event. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Sounds like a very bad architectural decision I'm afraid.. You should rethink your application logic...

Comment: I totally agree with you. Some idiot made a bunch of methods private in the base class and I have to do acrobats to fail before it gets to MyBtn_Click2, which is the click event subscribed to in the base class. I didn't show this to simplify the code. It's a software vendor so I can't change the base class.

Comment: You could add a CustomValidator that uses the Captcha to determine whether it's valid or not.

Comment: Unfortunately, the ValidationGroup isn't working when applied to the captcha. I suspect the software vendor again. I'm in hacking mode now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally use a hidden field and mark it as required. Put a default value in it, and if your captcha fails, remove the value and revalidate the page.

```
if (!CaptchaControl.IsValid)
{
    myHiddenField.Value = null;
    Page.Validate();
}
```

If your myBtn2 control is using `if (Page.IsValid)` to execute code, the hidden required field should be empty and now invalid.

Comment: Billiant, this worked! I'd rather switch software vendors, but thanks for this hack in the meantime :)